# How to inject Enums in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

How to inject Enums in TypeScript? Is this possible and recommended?

enums.ts:

```
export enum Environment {
    Development = 'Development',
    Production = 'Production',
    Test = 'Test'
}
```

file:

```
import { Environment as _Environment } from '../enums';
function myfunc(Environment: Environment = _Environment): void {}
```

I get:

```
application/libs/config/index.ts:23:18 - error TS2749: 'Environment' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

23     Environment: Environment = _Environment
```

Comment: Whats the `Environment` type? You've typed the parameter of your function to be of type `Environment`. Is that a type?

Comment: What about: `env: typeof Environment = _Environment`? Please see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiBuBLATgexBUAXKBvAsAFBQlQAiw8wANqgA6Yg4C8UA5BVbQ9mwDRFSUAApoAJmADGWROiis2o1BOmyQ-QaQAqwAM4t2O-WyIBfIkQBmYEKrkQAntdsAKUPABcULA7rBUlrAIKOiMBnBIaBjYAJRe8KiIYnimQA

Comment: @c_ogoo Ah so I can define a type which the enum can use?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. If you want to define parameter of type `Environment` with default value, it would be `function myfunc(environment: Environment = Environment.Development): void {}`. no need to define an alias (`as _Environment`)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
function myfunc(Environment: _Environment): void {}
```

However, if you want to utilize default parameters you can try something like this

```
function myfunc(Environment: _Environment = _Environment.Development): void {}
```

Comment: I'm trying to utilize default parameters in javascript

Answer (score 0):

[Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) is kind of union/variant type. It means that it defines group of possible values, but is not a value itself. Your function has an argument of type `Environment`, and it means that you can assign one of possible value existing in the enum `Enviroment`, but not Enum itself as you try to do, as `Enviroment` itself is not a value but a type.

```
function myfunc(Environment: Environment = _Environment.Production ): void {}
```

As you can see I am choosing arbitrarily one from possible values in the Enum.

You can look on Enums like on **unions with static structural representation**. It means that:

```
type T = 'a' | 'b';
enum TEnum {
  a = 'a'
  b = 'b'
}

// using
const a: T = 'a' // direct setting the value
const b: TEnum = TEnum.b // using existing enum structure to set the value
```

Comment: Ah. This makes sense. How would one create a pure function with Enums then, do you know?

Comment: Hi Karl. I don't fully follow your question. Enum is constant, if you use it inside the function it is still pure. It has enviroment dependency but it is still referential transparent within this enviroment. Feel free to use enums in any pure function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how  you would do it. Default envoronment being Development.

```
export enum Environment {
    Development = 'Development',
    Production = 'Production',
    Test = 'Test'
}

function myfunc(e: Environment = Environment.Development): void {}
```